# How to get a notification when someone has sent money using PayPal or Credit Card in Asp.NET?

Tags: asp.net, paypal, credit-card

How to get a notification when someone has sent money using PayPal or Credit Card in Asp.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using some sort of payment processor (like paypal)?  If so, they should have a way of notifying you when such an event occurs.  This is usually done with them POSTing the data to a URL that you given them in your account setup.  At that point it is as easy as having your site respond to POST requests with to that URL With webforms, this means either having an .aspx page, or [recommended] having a generic handler (ashx).  For MVC, you simply need to have an action method on the controller that the POST request is routed to.

HTH

Comment: thanks for answering. Anyway, do you have a good link to learn how to use the payment processor? Is it free to use the payment processor? I am new to this field. :-)

Comment: How are you getting paid currently?  Do users go to paypal directly and send the money to your email address?

Comment: Yes. The users go to paypal site and send money to my e-mail address.